# WinRT Xaml - Localizing a Button Style used in a DataTemplate

Tags: localization, styles, datatemplate, winrt-xaml

I'm trying to localize the text for a button. I have the following as the style:

```
<Style x:Key="MapPinAppBarButtonStyle" TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource AppBarButtonStyle}">
    <Setter Property="AutomationProperties.AutomationId" Value="MapPinAppBarButton"/>
    <!--<Setter Property="AutomationProperties.Name" Value="Drag to Map"/>-->
    <Setter Property="Content" Value="&#xE139;"/>
</Style>
```

This button style is being used on a button declared within a DataTemplate. The Uid is set to:

```
x:Uid="DragToMapButton"
```

The Resources.resw file contains an entry for:

```
DragToMapButton.[using:Windows.UI.Xaml.Automation]AutomationProperties.Name
```

This isn't working, there is an exception being thrown - however I cannot trap it - seems to be an internal Win32 exception.

Anyone have any idea on how to properly localize this value?

Answer (score 1):

You should assign Uid to setter

```
<Setter Property="AutomationProperties.Name" Value="Drag to Map" x:Uid="MapPinAppBarButtonName"/>
```

and add to resources "MapPinAppBarButtonName.Value"

Answer (score 0):

TargetType isn't Button, but ButtonBase.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. It's funny, because it doesn't work yesterday, but works now.

Look at this sample:
http://sdrv.ms/Tvtm4z

Comment: The sample isn't right, the button is within a DataTemplate which is being used in a GridView. A stand-alone button on a page - this works fine. I'm not sure how to translate a button in the case of it being within a DataTemplate.